# Bash ignore the $

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script which echo's in a postfix main.cf file

```
IPADD=$(ifconfig  | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}')
cat << EOG > /etc/postfix/main.cf
# LOCAL PATHNAME INFORMATION
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix

# QUEUE AND PROCESS OWNERSHIP
mail_owner = postfix
# SENDING MAIL
myorigin = $mydomain

# RECEIVING MAIL
mydestination = $myhostname localhost.$mydomain localhost $mydomain
# TRUST AND RELAY CONTROL
mynetworks_style = host
smtp_bind_address = $IPADD
inet_interfaces = $IPADD, 127.0.0.1

EOG
```

The problem is once you run the script, it strips out the "$mydomain" from:

```
 # SENDING MAIL
    myorigin = $mydomain
```

And also strips out the "$myhostname" and "$mydomain" from

```
# RECEIVING MAIL
    mydestination = $myhostname localhost.$mydomain localhost $mydomain
```

I would like the $IPADD to work and run, but would like it to ignore the "$" infront of $mydomain and $myhostname.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sh
cat << 'EOG' > /etc/postfix/main.cf
# other stuff
myorigin = $mydomain
# other stuff
EOG
```

[Here Document](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument)

Comment: Thank you, but this keeps all the $ , including $IPADDR, which I still need to run.

Comment: Ok thank you, if I split it, it works well. Thank you. i run $mydomain and $myhostname with 'EOG' and then cat in a new EOG for  $IPADD

Answer (score 0):

Using `$(echo '$a')` will do the trick:

```
a=1
cat  << EOF > /etc/postfix/main.cf
> test=$(echo '$a')
> foo=$a
> EOF
```

Output:

```
test=$a
foo=1
```